# How to make line plots in r for visualization as made in excel?

Tags: r, excel, plot

I am having a problem with generating line plots in r. I have the following table:

```
        7*7 6*6 5*5 4*4 3*3
Biodiff 728 436 0   0   0
EdgeR   728 638 421 132 34
DESeq   728 367 158 33  13
Cuff    728 596 493 256 138
```

Now I want to plot a line plot with this table as can be plotted in excel. I am  putting the image of the excel here but it is pretty straight forward approach to make marked line curve in excel. Now I want to create a similar one in R in which the values in the table are hard coded.

Can you please guide me how to do this?

[image: Line plot done in excel which shows number of gene output by each tool at different replicates]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to start from a single table construct a data.frame (since no numbers are allowed as first symbol in variable names I have written the numbers as words):

```
dat<-data.frame(method=c("Biodiff","EdgeR","DESeq","Cuff"),
            sevenXseven=c(728,728,728,728),
            sixXsix=c(436,638,367,596),
            fiveXfive=c(0,421,158,493),
            fourXfour=c(0,132,33,256),
            threeXthree=c(0,34,13,138))
```

I would suggest using the ggplot2 package. ggplot2 likes long table format instead of wide tables. With the reshape2 package you can melt the table into long format:

```
library(reshape2)
data<-melt(dat,id.vars="method",variable.name="cat")
```

You can plot the data with ggplot2 and mapping the method to a colour aesthetic:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data,aes(x=cat,y=value)) +
   geom_point(size=10,aes(colour=method)) +
   geom_line(aes(colour = method, group = method),size=2) +
   theme_bw()
```

And to make it look even more like your example you could try:

```
ggplot(data,aes(x=cat,y=value)) +
  geom_point(size=10,aes(colour=method,shape=method)) +
  geom_line(aes(colour = method, group = method),size=2) +
  scale_colour_discrete(name="") +
  scale_shape_discrete(guide="none") +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(y="Number of positive DE genes",x="")
```

[image: ggplot2 line plot with coloured groups]

Comment: Nice presentation, but dropping `reshape2` and `ggplot2` on someone who has not had experience plotting in R is ...interesting to say the least.